# Detect access modifier type on a property using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, access-modifiers

I have written some code to look at properties using reflection. I have retrieved a list of properties from the class using reflection.

However I need to find out if the property is public or protected. eg:

```
public string Name{get;set;}
protected  int Age{get;set;}
```

The PropertyInfo class does not seem to expose this information about the property. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since properties are just syntactic sugar over a pair of `get`/`set` methods, there's no such thing as "accessibility" of a property reflection-wise. Rather, you'll have to find out accessibility levels of `get` and `set` methods separately. To that end, retrieve appropriate `MethodInfo` objects with [`GetGetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getgetmethod.aspx) and [`GetSetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getsetmethod.aspx) methods, and from there are various `IsPrivate`, `IsPublic` and other methods and properties.

Answer (score 11):

You need to look at the methodInfo of each get & set method
eg :

```
PropertyInfo pi = ...;
bool isPublic = pi.GetGetMethod(true).IsPublic;
bool isProtected= pi.GetGetMethod(true).IsFamily;
```

It seems to be the IsFamily property that indicates if a method is protected..

Answer (score 9):

Wrote an extension method for this:

```
public static class ReflectionExt
{
    public static readonly List<AccessModifier> AccessModifiers = new List<AccessModifier>
    {
        AccessModifier.Private, 
        AccessModifier.Protected, 
        AccessModifier.ProtectedInternal,
        AccessModifier.Internal,  
        AccessModifier.Public
    };

    public static AccessModifier Accessmodifier(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.SetMethod == null)
            return propertyInfo.GetMethod.Accessmodifier();
        if (propertyInfo.GetMethod == null)
            return propertyInfo.SetMethod.Accessmodifier();
        var max = Math.Max(AccessModifiers.IndexOf(propertyInfo.GetMethod.Accessmodifier()),
            AccessModifiers.IndexOf(propertyInfo.SetMethod.Accessmodifier()));
        return AccessModifiers[max];
    }

    public static AccessModifier Accessmodifier(this MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (methodInfo.IsPrivate)
            return AccessModifier.Private;
        if (methodInfo.IsFamily)
            return AccessModifier.Protected;
        if (methodInfo.IsFamilyOrAssembly)
            return AccessModifier.ProtectedInternal;
        if (methodInfo.IsAssembly)
            return AccessModifier.Internal;
        if (methodInfo.IsPublic)
            return AccessModifier.Public;
        throw new ArgumentException("Did not find access modifier", "methodInfo");
    }
}
```

```
public enum AccessModifier
{
    Private,
    Protected,
    Internal,
    Public
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about `MethodInfo.IsFamilyOrAssembly` which represents `protected internal`. Also, you could remove the list and use the enum's ordinal value to calculate the max: `return (AccessModifier) Math.Max((int) property.GetMethod.Accessmodifier(), (int) property.SetMethod.Accessmodifier())`

Comment: @MrLore nice catch, i've updated the answer (you can do that too better).

Comment: Note the new-ish "private protected" access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main()
    {
        sample obj = new sample();
        Type t = obj.GetType();
        MethodInfo[] m = t.GetMethods();
        Console.WriteLine("Method Information:-\n\n");
        foreach (MethodInfo m1 in m)
            Console.WriteLine("Mthod name:" + m1.Name + "  \nMethod return type:" + m1.ReturnType + "\nIs staic:" + m1.IsStatic + "\nIs Public:" + m1.IsPublic + "\nIs Private:" + m1.IsPrivate);
        FieldInfo[] f = t.GetFields();
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nField Information:-\n\n");
        foreach(FieldInfo f1 in f)
            Console.WriteLine("Field name:" + f1.Name + "  \nField type:" + f1.FieldType + "\nIs staic:" + f1.IsStatic);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//.NET 6.0
namespace Test
{
    public enum AccessModifier
    {
        None,
        Private,
        Protected,
        ProtectedInternal,
        Internal,
        Public
    }

    class ReflectProperties
    {
        public class PersonInfo
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            internal string LastName { get; set; }
            protected int Age { get; set; }
            private string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
            protected internal Email {get; set; }
        }

        public static void WriteProperties()
        {
            var t = typeof(TestProperties).GetTypeInfo();

            foreach (var p in t.DeclaredProperties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Property name: {p.Name}");                
                Console.WriteLine($"Accessibility: {p.GetAccessmodifier()}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }    
       
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static AccessModifier GetAccessmodifier(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        {
            if (propertyInfo == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyInfo));

            var setterAccessibility = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(true)?.GetAccessmodifier() ?? AccessModifier.None;
            var getterAccessibility = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod(true)?.GetAccessmodifier() ?? AccessModifier.None;
            return Max(setterAccessibility, getterAccessibility);
        }

        private static AccessModifier Max(AccessModifier mod1, AccessModifier mod2)
        {
            if (mod1 == mod2 && mod2 == AccessModifier.None)
                throw new ArgumentException();            

            if (mod1 > mod2)
                return mod1;

            if (mod2 > mod1)
                return mod2;

            return mod1;
        }

        public static AccessModifier GetAccessmodifier(this MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            if (methodInfo.IsPrivate)
                return AccessModifier.Private;
            if (methodInfo.IsFamily)
                return AccessModifier.Protected;
            if (methodInfo.IsFamilyOrAssembly)
                return AccessModifier.ProtectedInternal;
            if (methodInfo.IsAssembly)
                return AccessModifier.Internal;
            if (methodInfo.IsPublic)
                return AccessModifier.Public;
            throw new ArgumentException("Did not find access modifier", "methodInfo");
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReflectProperties.WriteProperties();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide details about code

Comment: Is there a rule of the site broken?